# How to get variable by string?

Tags: java, android

I am new in java. I have a clickable objects `R.drawable.soccer` or `R.drawable.basketball` in android app.
When user click on image I know the string tag - "soccer" or "basketball".
How to get access  to object  `R.drawable.soccer_selected` by string "soccer" ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your question. Are you trying to get the Drawable soccer_selected?

```
if( myString.equalsIgnoreCase( "soccer" ) ){
    Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable( R.id.soccer_selected );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I mean, for example in javascript I can get access to object's property by a string or variable - R.id["soccer"] - that equal to  R.id.soccer, how to do the same in java?